# How is this a mismatched input?

Tags: pine-script

So apparently this keeps coming up with the error "Mismatched input ':' expecting ')'. If i break the code up half and cut off the -alertLevel and -impulseLevel parts it works fine, is it because it's so long in the original? Thanks! :)

bbc = (bbi>0 ? (bbi > alertLevel and bbi < impulseLevel ? col_above :na) : (bbi > impulseLevel ? col_peak : col_null) : (bbi < -alertLevel and bbi > -impulseLevel ? col_fall : na) : (bbi < -impulseLevel ? col_peak : col_null))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are merging two conditions then you will have to remove the na in the else condition and replace with second condition like below

bbc = (bbi>0 ? (bbi > alertLevel and bbi < impulseLevel ? col_above : (bbi > impulseLevel ? col_peak : col_null)) : (bbi < -alertLevel and bbi > -impulseLevel ? col_fall : (bbi < -impulseLevel ? col_peak : col_null)))

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using ternaries like this, maybe try with some if, else, else if?
It's easier to read

This part `(bbi > impulseLevel ? col_peak : col_null)` is executed when bbi is below 0
The part after doesn't make sense as the compilator will never execute that part`: (bbi < -alertLevel and bbi > -impulseLevel ? col_fall : na) : (bbi < -impulseLevel ? col_peak : col_null))`

Answer (score 0):

bbc = ( ... ? ( +++ ) : ( +++ ) : ( +++ ) : ( +++ ) )

and that's why...
count the number of colons in the same "if"